# Count the occurrences of an object in a list where multiple criteria are matching using LINQ

Tags: linq, count, grouping

I have a list of Cutdetails. I am trying to write a function using LINQ that will return the count of bars in the list where the CODE , BRAND, CODE and LENGTH all match. I want to be able to specify all these parameters and return a number for the number of matches.

I have tried using foreach statements which is fine but i'm sure there is an neater and smarter way to do it using LINQ. Any suggestions?

```
List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();

public class Bar
{
    public string Brand { set; get; }
    public string System { set; get; }
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Length { set; get; }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Will

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using the match and then do a count.

```
var occurences = bars.Where(x => x.Brand == "Brand" && x.Code == "code").Count();
```